# codeigniter 4 session data lost after redirect from payment gateway

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4, ccavenue

PHP 7.3.23 with CI 4.0.4 I am redirecting to ccavenue payment gateway after the payment is done, the session data is lost. And it shows message in console as:

> "Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by
> specifying its SameSite attribute." Because a cookie's SameSite
> attribute was not set or is invalid, it defaults to SameSite=Lax,
> which prevents the cookie from being sent in a cross-site request.
> This behavior protects user data from accidentally leaking to third
> parties and cross-site request forgery.

Comment: The warning appears because the SameSite policy for a cookie has not specified explicitly. read the details-  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

Answer (score 0):

You most likely do want to keep your session cookies set to `SameSite=Lax` for improved protection against CSRF attacks. It sounds as if your payment gateway sends a `POST` request to return the user to your site.

You should either:

- Process that returning request without the session cookie. e.g. that request should have everything in the payload for you to determine if the transaction was a success. You can then show a status page or similar with links to allow the user to continue to other pages. Following any of those links will be a same-site navigation and will include your session cookies again.
- Use the `POST`/Redirect/`GET` pattern, where you process the incoming `POST` request to extract the details from it, then perform a redirect to another page on your site, that `GET` request is a same-site request and your session cookies will be available again.

I've also explained this here: https://goo.gle/samesite-3d-secure